# copy list inside function python

Tags: python, list, copy

I am getting frustrated with this code, I've read some articles, but it seems I wasn't figure it out:

```
class c:
def __init__(self):
    self.k = [9, 8]
def a(x):
    k = c()
    x = k.k

l = [1, 9]
a(l)

print l # expects [9, 8], got [1, 9]
```

update, I found a rather rogue way:

```
class c:
    def __init__(self):
        self.k = [9, 8]
def a(x):
    k = c()
    for i in reversed(x):
        x.remove(i)
    for i in k.k:
         x.append(i)


l = [1, 9]
a(l)

print l # output [9, 8]
```

Comment: Those last two lines have nothing to do with the class `c`. You're just defining a list whose second element is 9, so printing `l[1]` will get you 9. Why do you expect it to be anything else? Did you mean to call `c.a(l)`?

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult for me to tell what you are *trying* to do. Let me make some assumption and point a few things out.

Your corrected code:

```
class C:     # by convention, Python classes are capitalized...
    def __init__(self):
        self.k = 10       
    def a(self, x):       # you need 'self' to refer to what instance
        x[1] = self.k
```

Now you can do what I *think* you are trying to do:

```
>>> c=C()          # you need an instance of that object
>>> li=[1,2]
>>> c.a(li)
>>> li
[1, 10]
```

The attribute `k` has the same scope as `c`, so if you want `.k` to be global make `c` global:

```
>>> c.k
10
>>> c.k=22
>>> c.k
22
```

Comment: Hi, I was a bit drunk at the time I posted this question, currently it's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt in my country though.

Comment: Hi, I was also try to make sstate global, but it does not solve problem.

Comment: sorry, i mean the k variable in a() function.

Comment: The attribute `k` has the same scope as the object `c`. So to access or change `k` just access the attribute. `print c.k` or `c.k=22`  Happy Tet and no posting while drinking ;-)